# Python Classes exercise not working from parent class

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have the following exercise, but I am unable to understand completely how to make it work.

Develop a program that consists of:

1- A parent class Account that contains:

**Attributes:**

- text type Name
- integer type quantity(money in the account)

Also cointains a Method that returns the data in the Account class.

2- Define two classes FixedTime and Savings that inherit from the Account class, where

**The Savings class**

- Define the **init** that passes the data inherited from the Account Class
- You will have a method that prints the information.

**The FixedTime class will have:**

Define the **init** that passes the data inherited from the Account Class as well
to have:

- attribute term type integer
- floating rate interest attribute.

Methods:

- Method to obtain the amount of interest to be returned by the result of
  (amount * interest / 100) 2. Method to display the information, data of the holder, term, interest and total of
  interest.
  Create a main program where you define a variable of the class FixedTime and Savings,
  Fill in the necessary information and validate the functionality of each indicated method.

I have the following code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount

class Saving(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        Account.__init__(self, name, amount)
    def  get_info(self):
        print(f"{self.name}, {self.amount}")

class Fixrate(Account):
    def __init__(self, rate, time):
        self.rate = rate
        self.time = time
    def total_import(self):
        total = (self.amount * self.rate)/ 100
        return total
    def rate_info_print(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.name} term: {self.time} rate: {self.rate} Total rate: {self.total_import()}")


person = Account("andres", 5000)
date = Fixrate(4.5, 4)
Saving.get_info(person)
Fixrate.rate_info_print(person)
```

I am getting this error:

print(f"Name: {self.name} term: {self.time} rate: {self.rate} Total rate: {self.total_import()}")
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'time'

Comment: And what's your question?  By the way, the assignment said the field was supposed to be called `quantity` not `amount`, and the third class is supposed to be `FixedTime`, not `Fixedrate`.

Comment: Instead of `Saving.get_info(person)`, you use `person.get_info()`, or you would if `person` were a `Saving` object, which it is not.  Did you mean to create `Saving` instead of `Account`?  And you write `date.rate_info_print()`, not `Fixrate.rate_info_print(person)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need assign `time` and `name` in `Fixrate __init__`
- you create a instance to `Fixrate` called `date`, then you should use it rather than use `Fixrate.rate_info_print(person)`

code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount

class Saving(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        super().__init__(name, amount)
    def get_info(self):
        print(f"{self.name}, {self.amount}")

class Fixrate(Account):
    def __init__(self, rate, time, name, amount):
        self.rate = rate
        self.time = time
        super(Fixrate, self).__init__(name,amount)

    def total_import(self):
        total = (self.amount * self.rate)/ 100
        return total
        
    def rate_info_print(self):
        print(f"Name: {self.name} term: {self.time} rate: {self.rate} Total rate: {self.total_import()}")


person = Account("andres", 5000)
date = Fixrate(4.5, 4,"andres",5000)
Saving.get_info(person)
date.rate_info_print()
```

result:

```
andres, 5000
Name: andres term: 4 rate: 4.5 Total rate: 225.0
```

or if you want to make use of `person`, you can try this one.

code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount

class Saving(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, amount):
        super().__init__(name, amount)
    def get_info(self):
        print(f"{self.name}, {self.amount}")

class Fixrate(Account):
    def __init__(self, rate, time, person):
        self.rate = rate
        self.time = time
        self.person = person
        # super(Fixrate, self).__init__(name,amount)

    def total_import(self):
        total = (self.amount * self.rate)/ 100
        return total
        
    def rate_info_print(self):
        self.name = person.get_name()
        self.amount = person.get_amount()
        print(f"Name: {self.name} term: {self.time} rate: {self.rate} Total rate: {self.total_import()}")


person = Account("andres", 5000)
date = Fixrate(4.5, 4,person)
Saving.get_info(person)
date.rate_info_print()
```

result:

```
andres, 5000
Name: andres term: 4 rate: 4.5 Total rate: 225.0
```